What is the difference between $\sigma^2$ and $s^2_U$ in Simple Random Sampling?
I am currently studying Simple Random Sampling in a statistics and i am confused on the notation being used.
One theorem gives the following notation:
Consider SRS for samples of size n in a population of size N. Let $y_i$ denote the responses, i= 1,...,N, and let
$$ \bar{y}_U = \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}y_i \\ \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2 \\ s^2_U=\frac{N}{N-1}\sigma^2$$
where $\bar{y}_U$ and $\sigma^2$ denotes the population mean and population variance, respectively.
But at no point does it explain what $s^2_U$ is. And then the next theorem gives the following notation:
For a SRS,the sample variance $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\in S}(y_i-\bar{y})^2$ is an unbiased estimator for the population variance $s^2_U = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum^{N}_{i=1}(y_i-\bar{y}U)^2$
So in the 2nd theorem s^2_U is denoted as the population variance. But why is this different from in the first theorem. What's the point in having the two different notation?
